# How to checkin on TFS without error of common .vs and packages in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs

I have an application in visual studio 2017 and I have upload that application on TFS before few days. Now I have made some changes and I want to upload latest code on TFS so when I am going to checkin my code on TFS then every time it's giving me different error like 
`"The process cannot access the file...v15\Server\sqlite3\storage.ide-shm' because it is being used by another process."`. Also some times it's giving error like
 `"server sqlite3 db lock because it is being used by another process"`.
I have check for it's solution and almost every solution suggest for delete vs folder and then checkin code on TFS. So when I delete vs folder and again start my project then again vs folder create automatically. And again I am getting same issue.

So how to upload/communicate with TFS without this types issue ?

Comment: I am using TFS. Yes I am excluding .vs and package folder at checking time.

Comment: Yes, you tagged your question as TFS. That's not what I asked however. TFS has two built in source control options. Git and TFVC. Which are you using?

Comment: Sorry but I am not aware about it. Please can you suggest me that how can I check it ?

Answer (score -1):

These files that are giving you the error should not be part of your repository. They are files used by Visual Studio and don't need to be checked in.
TFVC and other source control system have an option to exclude these files when checking in your code.

If you're using the TFS' TFVC for source control you can add a `.tfignore` file in the Source Control Explorer and in it you list the files that you want to exclude.

If you're using GIT for source control with TFS you can add a `.gitingore` file in your repo and in it you list the files that you want to exclude.

Note that you might not have add each file in the .ignore one by one. GIT has predefined `.gitingore` file to exclude all these unnecessary files.

Here is a short video on how to use .tfignore: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfKcTX8NxAQ